# How to design a web application using georeferenced aerial imagery

Tags: api, web

I'm working on a web application that monitors the state of plants in their respective fields, of which we are taking georeferenced aerial imagery with a drone.

Unfortunately I'm new to this technology, but what I would like to do is to present those fields via a web application displaying points on those maps each of which will represent a plant.

Do I need to store all the aerial images on the local server and install some kind of provider locally or should I load them on a gis service and access them via an API and add my points on the map received?

Answer (score 1):

For displaying imagery on a web map, probably you want a WMS or WMTS, if you want to query or manipulate the imagery, you'll want a WCS +/- WCPS service. For displaying/querying points (as an image) use a WMS, for displaying/querying points as vectors use a WFS (with WFS-T if you want to manipulate the data in the client).

Comment: I wanted to use my georeferenced imagery in my web app mainly for the detail, with the aerial scan we did I can get a cleaner representation for the points on the map (drawing 4k points on a 3-5 ha area with a fixed max zoom of a wms results massive visual clutter)

what I wanted to know is that if I can have a local gis application serving my own imagery referenced on a map to my application and then draw on it all the points I need and alter their state ((e.g: the health condition of a plant). Or load my imagery on an external service and have it provide maps to my app in a wms fashion.